# Редактирование данных django и forms.Select

Tags: python, django

Я использую виджет и в шаблоне `datalist`. Но при редактировании данных, в `input datalist` не подгружается уже сохраненное значение. Как это сделать? подставляется значение *+7*, которое указано в `_forms_clients_datalist.html`

**forms**

```
class ListTextWidget(forms.Select):
    template_name = 'include/_forms_clients_datalist.html'

class PhoneInputField(forms.CharField):
    widget=ListTextWidget()

class RelatedAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = PhoneInputField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['phone'].choices = Clients.objects.order_by('-phone').values_list('phone')
```

**_forms_clients_datalist.html**

```
<input id="ajax_phone_{{ widget.name }}" list="{{ widget.name }}"
    {% if widget.value != None %} name="{{ widget.name }}" value="+7" {% endif %}
    {% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %} autocomplete="off">
    <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-warning text-dark" id="ajax-{{ widget.name }}" name="ajax-{{ widget.name }}"></span>

<datalist id="{{ widget.name }}">
    <optgroup label="">
    </optgroup>
</datalist><br>
```

Comment: вы не выводите `widget.value`. Полагаю проблема в этом. А точнее в `{% if widget.value != None %} name="{{ widget.name }}" value="+7" {% endif %}`

Comment: попробуйте вывести `value="{{widget.value}}"`

Comment: да, помогло, но есть проблема, в том, что при создании формы должно подставляться "+7", а в таком случае, поле пустое. как перехватить именно создание, а не редактирование?

Comment: в форме можете переопределить метод `clean()` и подправить значение как вам надо. либо в `save()` модели.  В обоих случах нужно будет проверять, что номер уже не начинается с +7 чтобы его изменить